# Problems connecting postgres with sequelize.js dialect

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postgres database and want to set the dialect on sequelize as postgres. I followed all the instructions on the sequelize.js site mainly:

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'postgres', 'pword', {
host: "localhost", //your server
port: 5432 //server port
dialect: 'postgres' 
});
```

I also did these modifications in the package.json file:

```
"name": "hello-world",
"description": "hello world test app",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "express": "3.1",
  "pg": "0.8.8",
  "sequelize": "1.6.x"
}
```

But when I try to run node app.js I get this error:
dialect: 'postgres'
  ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)

I'm really confused what is going on, and why I'm still getting this error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the comment lines after host and port.

Comment: My pleasure. Getting started can be the hardest part, but I've been really happy with Sequelize after two intense months. Stick with it.